# Who sends pings in MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, libmosquitto

The keepalive feature in MQTT helps detecting connection problems. That is, if the broker has not received any data from the client in `1.5 * keepalive` seconds, it considers the client disconnected. But who should send periodic pings when keepalive is enabled? Broker or client?

The MQTT standard at http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349238 states that the client must send PINGREQ packets if it has no other data to send.

On another hand, `mosquitto_connect()` function of libmosquitto (https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_connect) has the following description of `keepalive` parameter:

> keepalive:    the number of seconds after which the broker should send a PING message to the client if no other messages have been exchanged in that time.

I wanted to clear up this confusion. I lean towards the variant from MQTT standard, but would like to know for sure. Also maybe this indicates a bug in libmosquitto implementation?

Specifically, I use libmosquitto version 1.6.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in documentation of libmosquitto.

The MQTT standard does not specify a way for the broker to initiate ping messages, only to respond to them. The [implementation](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/a8448a9c7b14bdaee6ec80419d43fd6544e789b6/lib/util_mosq.c#L91-L99) in libmosquitto client library appears to use the `keepalive` parameter for periodically sending packets to the broker, just like the standard specifies.

So it seems the documentation should read:

> keepalive: the number of seconds after which the **client** should send a PING message to the **broker** if no other messages have been exchanged in that time.